# How to display the last child div at all times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically, I need to display the last child `div` inside its parent at all times using a jQuery's scroll effect.

The content of parent `div` is generated via PHP by the way.

Here is my current code so far:

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="chattercontent" style="width:65%; display:block;">
    <div id="messageme">
        <div>PHP GENERATED CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
        <div>PHP GENERATED CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
        <div>PHP GENERATED CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
        <div>PHP GENERATED CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
        <div>PHP GENERATED CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
        <div>PHP GENERATED CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript that I use inside an ajax for the scroll effect:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
```

JavaScript that I tried to use to display the last `div` child at all times:

```
<script>
    $( "#messageme div:last-child" )
    .css({ color:"red", fontSize:"80%" })
</script>
```

Comment: make a fiddle for it please

Comment: And what is it currently doing?

Comment: @EvanKnowles, current does nothing.. it has no affect on the last div child. it doesn't change the css either....

Comment: Is `<script>` in `<head>`? If so, wrap code with `$(document).ready(function() { your code });`

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/o64t6tkt/

Comment: @Mr.Alien ...works with "onDomready" option in it. It's worth to mention.

Comment: @Regent Obviously, ain't sure if he doesn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of referencing

```
$(document).height()
```

You will want to reference your selector

```
$( "#messageme div:last-child" )
```

So your code would look like

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $( "#messageme div:last-child" ) }, 'slow');
```

If you want to change the color after the animation you can add a callback.

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $( "#messageme div:last-child" ) }, 'slow', function() {
    //Do stuff after the animation is done
    $( "#messageme div:last-child" ).css({ color:"red", fontSize:"80%" })
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewzzxccx/).